# Yii2: How to filter in a custom ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: filter, yii2

I made this ActiveDataProvider:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query->asArray(), // It is a simple SQL query.
    'key' => 'item',
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'item',
            'quantity',
        ],
    ]
]);
```

I need to add the filters for **item** and **quantity** because it doesn't work (it doesn't search):

[image: item and quantity filter don't work]

Comment: Do you want to sort ascending or descending on those attributes?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. I only need the write inside the field and search.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: your question isnt clear why isnt it working? show the complete search model, and the view code for the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You must have not set your attributes item and quantity as [`safe`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#safe-attributes) in your SearchModel [`rules()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#declaring-rules), method.

You have to set them as [`safe`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#safe-attributes) in SearchModel.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['item', 'quantity'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

In your case, your Data Provider should be simply like this:

```
// It is not necessary to use "$query->asArray()", because your "$query" itself is object of ActiveQuery
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'key' => 'item',
    ]);
```

Comment: Try after removing sort from ActiveDataProvider.